# DAX syntax to compare a list to another list

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a string column, which contains a list of string values separated by commas.

[image]

I converted the column into a List by using M syntax

[image]

Now I would like to write a DAX query that would compare the Names column with a criteria table and return a row if there are intersections. Something like this:

`FILTER(Users, INTERSECTSWITH(Users[Names], {{"Joe", "Meg"}}))`

which should return rows 1 and 3.
INTERSECTSWITH does not exist in DAX, but is there an equivalent technique to compare one list to another?

Thanks!